# Selecting MAX() of a SUM() query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create a query that shows the max value along with the team name from a sum query. I've tried searching around and most of the answers uses LIMIT and TOP 1 which is not really what I'm looking for.

So from this SUM query :

```
SELECT Team_Name, SUM(SCORE) as Score_Total
FROM SCORE, TEAM
WHERE team.Team_ID = score.Team_ID
GROUP BY Team_Name;
```

Returns this:

```
+----------------+-------------+
|   Team_Name    | Score_Total |
+----------------+-------------+
| Hackers        |         332 |
| Hammer Time    |         356 |
| Sharp Shooters |         406 |
| String Music   |         355 |
+----------------+-------------+
```

And when I attempt to use the MAX function out of the sum query with the following code:

```
SELECT Team_Name, MAX(Score_Total)
FROM (
SELECT Team_Name, SUM(SCORE) as Score_Total
FROM SCORE, TEAM
WHERE team.Team_ID = score.Team_ID
GROUP BY Team_Name) s;
```

I get this:

```
+-----------+------------------+
| Team_Name | MAX(Score_Total) |
+-----------+------------------+
| Hackers   |              406 |
+-----------+------------------+
```

As you can see the max value is indeed right but the team name that corresponds with the max value is not. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Could you please provide your table schemas / structures?  It would mean the difference between an effective answer and a working one; because this could all be solved with a few UNION Joins.

Comment: @dockeryZ Here you go. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b0da

Answer (score 2):

Consider this query:

```
SELECT Team_Name, MAX(Score_Total), MIN(Score_Total)
FROM (
SELECT Team_Name, SUM(SCORE) as Score_Total
FROM SCORE, TEAM
WHERE team.Team_ID = score.Team_ID
GROUP BY Team_Name) s;
```

Which team name should it return? The team with the greatest score total or the team with the least score total? What if the aggregate is `AVG()` and *none* of the rows contain the value?

The team name does not come from the row where the max (or min) value is found. In fact, MySQL is allowing a query that is ambiguous. It returns one of the many team names in the column, but it's arbitrary which team it returns.

Note that "arbitrary" does not mean "random." In practice, MySQL returns the first value it finds in the group. But this is not part of guaranteed behavior, and it's only a coincidence of the implementation. If they change the implementation in some future version, and it starts returning a differently chosen arbitrary row from the group, you aren't allowed to complain. ;-)

This type of query is actually an error in most brands of SQL, and in the SQL standard. You can make MySQL behave more strictly according the the SQL standard with `SET SQL_MODE=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

The easiest solution to your problem is this:

```
SELECT Team_Name, SUM(SCORE) as Score_Total
FROM SCORE, TEAM
WHERE team.Team_ID = score.Team_ID
GROUP BY Team_Name
ORDER BY Score_Total DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I see your point. Is there a way to do link each team name with the total score values? I've seen examples where INNER JOIN is used. Will it work?

Comment: See the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag. Variations on this type of query have been asked and answered frequently.

Answer (score 1):

When you do not specify a group-by condition in a query, MySQL returns any random value.

If you want the max vaue from your subquery, I suggest you order the data set and then fetch only the first row:

```
select team_name, score_total
from
    (
        select team_name, sum(score) as score_total
        from score, team
        where team.team_id = score.team_id
        group by team_name
    ) as a
order by
    score_total desc
limit 1;
```

---

A little suggestion:

Insetad of doing a cartesian join and filtering on the `where` clause, use a join. Also, group by an Id field:

```
select team_name, score_total
from
    (
        select team_name, sum(score) as score_total
        from 
            score as s 
            inner join team as t on s.team_id = t.team_id
        group by 
            t.team_id
    ) as a
order by
    score_total desc
limit 1;
```

---

A simpler way:

```
select team_name, sum(score) as score_total
from score as s inner join team as t on s.team_id = s.team_id
group by team_id
order by sum(score) desc
limit 1
```

Comment: There's no difference in optimization between comma-style joins (SQL-89) and `JOIN` syntax joins (SQL-92). They both invoke the same code internally. I prefer the SQL-92 style too, but for different reasons.

Comment: @BillKarwin I prefer the join style because it helps me see clearly the relations between the tables. I like to keep the relations stuff in the `from` clause, and the filters stuff in the `where` (and / or `having`) clause

Comment: Same here. It reduces the risk that you join 7 tables but only write 5 join conditions. Old style join syntax makes it harder to find which condition goes with each pair of tables. My only point is that in MySQL, the SQL-89 style *doesn't* do a cartesian join and then filter the results. Both styles perform a nested-loop join.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so according to your table structure, you can do this

```
SELECT t1.Team_Name, SUM(s1.score) as score FROM SCORE s1
INNER JOIN TEAM t1 USING (Team_ID)
GROUP BY s1.Team_ID
UNION
SELECT t2.Team_Name, MAX(s2.score) as maxscore FROM SCORE s2
INNER JOIN TEAM t2 USING (Team_ID)
GROUP BY s2.Team_ID
UNION
SELECT t3.Team_Name, MIN(s3.score) as minscore FROM SCORE s3
INNER JOIN TEAM t3 USING (Team_ID)
GROUP BY s3.Team_ID
```